# Error in AutoDock-Vina installing and runnig on Ubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

I am a Research Student. I used to MSWindows but I am new to Linux.
I have Lubuntu 18.04 system. I am trying to install AutoDock-Vina as guided by:

https://netmiko.com/linux/install-autodock-vina-ubuntu

I am get error while I press ADT (or PMV) in LXTerminal:

```
alma@alma-HP-Notebook:~$ adt
setting PYTHONHOME environment
Run ADT from  /home/alma/ADV/mgltools_x86_64Linux2_1.5.6/MGLToolsPckgs/AutoDockTools
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alma/ADV/mgltools_x86_64Linux2_1.5.6/MGLToolsPckgs/AutoDockTools/__init__.py", line 429, in runADT
    from Pmv.moleculeViewer import MoleculeViewer
  File "/home/alma/ADV/mgltools_x86_64Linux2_1.5.6/MGLToolsPckgs/Pmv/moleculeViewer.py", line 21, in <module>
    from DejaVu.Geom import Geom
  File "/home/alma/ADV/mgltools_x86_64Linux2_1.5.6/MGLToolsPckgs/DejaVu/__init__.py", line 200, in <module>
    from Viewer import Viewer
  File "/home/alma/ADV/mgltools_x86_64Linux2_1.5.6/MGLToolsPckgs/DejaVu/Viewer.py", line 45, in <module>
    from opengltk.OpenGL import GL
  File "/home/alma/ADV/mgltools_x86_64Linux2_1.5.6/MGLToolsPckgs/opengltk/OpenGL/GL.py", line 7, in <module>
    from opengltk.extent._gllib import *
ImportError: libGLU.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
hit enter to continue
```

Comment: Hello. As this version is long past EOL it is off topic on this site. Lubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver) was released April 27, 2018 and will reach End of Life on Friday, April 30, 2021.

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE (*not Lubuntu*).

Comment: More FYI:   Ubuntu (and *flavors* use a *year.month* format for releases; ie. 18.04 tells you it was the 2018-April release which had 3 years of support for LTS *flavors*, 5 years for main Ubuntu Desktop, Server, Cloud etc, & 9 months for non-LTS. Ubuntu also has some *specialist* products that use the *year* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 20 for 2020 release) which come with 10 years of supported life.  With 18.04 you're no longer using Lubuntu (*it's oldest supported release is 20.04*) but main Ubuntu 18.04 with LXDE when you want support.

Comment: What I can do? pls tell.

Comment: The link you provided assumed you're using a much newer software stack (ie. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) Maybe try following a set of instructions that match your *older* software stack... the `python3` errors maybe the result of you using the two year older `python3` (*on an EOL version of Lubuntu*)

Comment: I am upgrading Lubuntu18.04 to Lubuntu20.04.04LTS, some my data in computer, it will not destroy while upgrading?

Comment: Don't forget Lubuntu 18.04 was the *end of the road* with regards upgrades.  As the release notes (and other sites said): "*Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please do a fresh install.*"    https://lubuntu.me/focal-2-released/   That notice was dropped from notices when Lubuntu 18.04 LTS reached EOL after April-2021 as users should have already upgraded.

Answer (score -1):

I am currently running fedora35. I faced similar problem when I tried to run adt from command line. It gives the same error
ImportError: libGLU.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
hit enter to continue
As the error indicates, I have no libGLU. So, I downloaded mesa-libGLU-9.0.1-5.fc35.x86_64.rpm and installed it. No further error message displayed since then. Below given link may be of some help.
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwig5rn71Z33AhWGR2wGHcy5B4sQFnoECAUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpkgs.org%2Fdownload%2FlibGLU.so.1()(64bit)&usg=AOvVaw1ancDYIvnZ_Jk9oD6zOmFZ